# Horror anime about vampires hunted down by humans

Tags: shiki

Hello :) so I saw only part of it a while back and so I only know a little bit about it.

It was definitely on the horror side - there were humans vs vampires and (I dont know if it was for just that episode or if it was the entire series) but the humans were the ones hunting down the vampires. The vampires weren't evil and were just regular humans, but the humans were rude.

The scene I saw went something like this:
Some vampires are crawling through a narrow tunnel (head to butt) trying to escape the humans - they are obviously panicked and some are crying. Then one by one, the humans begin to rip them out of the tunnel. Pretty gruesome. After they rip them all out, you can see a massacre of bodies around as a large man comes up to one of the vampires (Who is burning, if I remember correctly because of the sun) and he says something that makes it evident that his son was killed by a vampire and then he kills her and the rest of the humans around him console him.

I'm afraid that is all I know, any help would be extremely appreciated! <3

Comment: It reminds me one episode of [Shiki](http://myanimelist.net/anime/7724/Shiki), I don't remember exactly which one...

Comment: I am also fairly certain it is shiki. @Dario you might want to post it as a answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like [**Shiki**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/7724/Shiki):

[image]

> When citizens of a secluded village begin dying off in alarming numbers, the sole hospital's head doctor tries desperately to save his patients—but his efforts are in vain. Entire families are wiped out while others desert their homes. All hell breaks loose as the villagers discover their loved ones' corpses are rising from the grave with an insatiable thirst for human blood. Who is safe when the urge to kill in order to survive blurs the line between man and monster?

- It is pretty gruesome especially in showing humans killing vampires
- In the beginning of the series vampires kills humans without letting them realize they were actually killed (they just considered theirs as unexplained deaths)... When humans realize the existence of vampires they begin to hunt them down.
- I think the scene you described is taken from **Episode 20.5**: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy_Dcp5Ljp4) is a clip from that episode.
  [image]